# Can't ReDim multidimensional array preserving the data

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, vbscript

Does anyone know why I can `ReDim` a multidimensional array without the `Preserve` keyword, but if I want to preserve it it fail? This seems to work fine on one-dimensional arrays though.

This works but deletes old data:

```
Dim marray()
ReDim marray(2,3)
WScript.Echo "marray ubound = " & UBound(marray)

marray(0, 0) = "item 0,0"
marray(0, 1) = "item 0,1"
marray(0, 2) = "item 0,2"
marray(0, 3) = "item 0,3"
marray(1, 0) = "item 1,0"
marray(1, 1) = "item 1,1"
marray(1, 2) = "item 1,2"
marray(1, 3) = "item 1,3"
marray(2, 0) = "item 2,0"
marray(2, 1) = "item 2,1"
marray(2, 2) = "item 2,2"
marray(2, 3) = "item 2,3"

For Each item In marray
    WScript.Echo item
Next

ReDim marray(UBound(marray)+2, 3)
WScript.Echo "New marray ubound = " & UBound(marray)
marray(3, 0) = "item 3,0"
marray(3, 1) = "item 3,1"
marray(3, 2) = "item 3,2"
marray(3, 3) = "item 3,3"
marray(4, 0) = "item 4,0"
marray(4, 1) = "item 4,1"
marray(4, 2) = "item 4,2"
marray(4, 3) = "item 4,3"

For Each item In marray
    WScript.Echo item
Next
```

This should keep the data, but doesn't work.

```
Dim marray()
ReDim marray(2,3)
WScript.Echo "marray ubound = " & UBound(marray)

marray(0, 0) = "item 0,0"
marray(0, 1) = "item 0,1"
marray(0, 2) = "item 0,2"
marray(0, 3) = "item 0,3"
marray(1, 0) = "item 1,0"
marray(1, 1) = "item 1,1"
marray(1, 2) = "item 1,2"
marray(1, 3) = "item 1,3"
marray(2, 0) = "item 2,0"
marray(2, 1) = "item 2,1"
marray(2, 2) = "item 2,2"
marray(2, 3) = "item 2,3"

For Each item In marray
    WScript.Echo item
Next

ReDim Preserve marray(UBound(marray)+2, 3)
WScript.Echo "New marray ubound = " & UBound(marray)
marray(3, 0) = "item 3,0"
marray(3, 1) = "item 3,1"
marray(3, 2) = "item 3,2"
marray(3, 3) = "item 3,3"
marray(4, 0) = "item 4,0"
marray(4, 1) = "item 4,1"
marray(4, 2) = "item 4,2"
marray(4, 3) = "item 4,3"

For Each item In marray
    WScript.Echo item
Next
```

The error messag is:

> arrays.vbs(19, 1) Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Subscript out of range)

Comment: "If you use Preserve, you can resize only the last dimension of the array." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/redim-statement#example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a multi-dimensional array you need to tell `UBound` which dimension it should check.

```
>>> ReDim arr(2, 3)
>>> WScript.Echo UBound(arr, 1)
2
>>> WScript.Echo UBound(arr, 2)
3
>>> ReDim Preserve arr(UBound(arr, 1), UBound(arr, 2)+1)
>>> WScript.Echo UBound(arr, 1)
2
>>> WScript.Echo UBound(arr, 2)
4
```

Note also, that you can only change the *last* dimension of a multi-dimensional array (while preserving the data). Trying to change the other dimensions will produce an error:

```
>>> ReDim arr(2, 3)
>>> ReDim Preserve arr(UBound(arr, 1)+1, UBound(arr, 2))
Subscript out of range (0x9)
```

From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c850dt17):

> ### Remarks
>
> [...]
>
> If you use the `Preserve` keyword, you can resize only the last array dimension, and you can't change the number of dimensions at all. [...]

If you need to be able to change multiple dimensions you need a jagged array (an array of arrays):

```
>>> ReDim arr(2)
>>> WScript.Echo UBound(arr)
2
>>> arr(0) = Array()
>>> WScript.Echo UBound(arr(0))
-1
>>> ReDim Preserve arr(UBound(arr)+1)
>>> WScript.Echo UBound(arr)
3
```

Beware, though, that with a jagged array you need to resize the nested arrays individually, and you can't do it directly.

```
>>> ReDim arr(2)
>>> arr(0) = Array()
>>> WScript.Echo UBound(arr(0))
-1
>>> ReDim Preserve arr(0)(UBound(arr(0))+1)  'this doesn't work!
Expected end of statement (0x401)
>>> tmp = arr(0)                             'need a temp variable
>>> ReDim Preserve tmp(UBound(tmp)+1)
>>> arr(0) = tmp
>>> WScript.Echo UBound(arr(0))
0
```

Comment: It's amazing what you can learn when you just take the time to read the documentation.